# I am new to django and python. Django URLs error: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

in Django 1.10, I get the error:

**TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().**

My urls.py is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'blogs.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

views.py code:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{})
```

Help me

Comment: See the duplicate question for a full explanation. In your case, add the import `from blogs import views`, then change the URL pattern to `url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),`.

Comment: If you're new to Django, start with the latest release, currently 1.11.X.